# Why use INDIRECT in place of direct reference in excel

Tags: excel

Why would one use `INDIRECT(cell)` instead of a direct reference to `cell`?

Eg, I see a sheet where there are many references

```
     A    B     C
1 SHEET1  B1  =INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!"&B1)
2 SHEET1  B2  =INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!"&B2)
3 SHEET1  B3  =INDIRECT("'"&A3&"'!"&B3)
```

Why not just

```
     A    B     C
1             =SHEET1$B1
2             =SHEET1$B2
3             =SHEET1$B3
```

Answer (score 0):

use case - programmatically list and loop a range of worksheets:
sheet references using formulas and values useful for addressing cells at scale.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Indirect` vs `Direct Cell Reference`

`does not generally auto update` vs `does update`

*example adding or removing columns*

`arithmetic to change row or column` vs `what you type is what you get`

*example indirect("A"&3+5) vs =A3+5 is totally different*

If you want to organize your formula references and change them all on the fly it is easier with indirect (although even easier just using the naming feature) but the real reason you "need" indirect is how else are you going to change the reference in your formula without manually typing it (answer: indirect)?

Answer (score 0):

### Build references to many different cells, worksheets or workbooks that follow a logic

The most common use of the `INDIRECT` function is probably when someone wants to reference to many cells which cell references follow a logical rule. For example, assume you have an Excel workbook with hundreds of sheets, one for each day and the sheet names are the dates. Now you would like to summarize some of the values in those sheets on an overview sheet. In this case, you can type in your starting date, drag it down to your final date (Excel will increment the dates). Using the `INDIRECT` function, you can now easily build up the references within seconds.

However, consider that `INDIRECT` is a **volatile** function which will slow down your workbook. Further, if you insert rows/columns, the `INDIRECT` function won’t adapt. It get’s even worse when you reference to external sheets. **Since `INDIRECT` updates it’s value with every change in the workbook**, you will get `#REF` errors as soon as you close the referenced sheets.
I personally avoid `INDIRECT` for such cases (either using VBA or by choosing a different design for my workbooks, so no `INDIRECT` function is necessary)

### Lock a cell reference

If you have a cell reference like let’s say `=A10`, Excel will always adapt the reference when you insert new rows or columns (if you for example insert a row above row `10`, the reference changes to `=A11`). You can use the `INDIRECT` function in order to always keep the absolute cell reference: `=INDIRECT(“A10”)`.

### With named ranges

INDIRECT can be handy with named references. Have a look at the example where you have three named ranges:

- NorthAmerica: `B2:B5`
- Europe: `C2:C5`
- Asia: `D2:D5`

[image: Using the INDIRECT function in Excel with named ranges]

You can now combine the `INDIRECT` function with many other Excel functions like `SUM`, `MIN`, `MAX` and so on. In the example, the drop down selection in G1 is referenced using `INDIRECT` to perform the calculation for the selected range.

### Dynamic dropdowns

A similar example where you can use the `INDIRECT` function are dynamic drop downs. In this example there are two named ranges:

- Fruits: `A2:A4`
- Vegetables: `B2:B4`

[image: Building dynamic drop downs in Excel using the INDIRECT function]

In cell `D3`, there is a dropdown where you can select “Fruits” or “Vegetables”. In `E3`, we have a dynamic drop down with the source `=INDIRECT($D$3)`. If you choose “Fruits” in `D3`, you will have a list with the fruits in the drop down.

So, there are definitely some things where `INDIRECT` might be an easy solution. But as I said, it is a volatile function that locks the cell reference. In most cases you can find different, better solutions. The main reason people use it is probably the lack of knowledge of better alternatives. In addition, I assume that the average Excel user is not aware of possible problems you might run into when using `INDIRECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Indirect is very useful with Tables.  For example, I create a table tblFindings with 10 rows.  Then I assign the list to =Indirect("tblFindings").  Now I add 5 rows to the table, the dropdown list automatically updates.